# How to get 10 Objects based on a value from the Object?

Tags: java

I have to create a method that gives the 10 Taxpayers that spent the most in the entire system.
There's a lot of classes already created and code that would have to be in between but what I need is something like:

```
public TreeSet<Taxpayer> getTenTaxpayers(){
    TreeSet<Taxpayer> taxp = new TreeSet<Taxpayer>();
    ... 
    for(Taxpayer t: this.taxpayers.values()){ //going through the Map<String, Taxpayer>
        for(Invoice i: this.invoices.values()){ //going through the Map<String, Invoice>
             if(taxp.size()<=10){ 
                if(t.getTIN().equals(i.getTIN())){ //if the TIN on the taxpayer is the same as in the Invoice
                     ...
                }
             }
        }
    }
    return taxp;
}
```

To sum it up, I have to go through a `Map<String, Taxpayer>` which has for example 100 Taxpayers, then go through a `Map<String, Invoice>` for each respective invoice and return a new Collection holding the 10 Taxpayers that spent the most on the entire system based on 1 attribute on the Invoice Class. My problem is how do I get those 10, and how do I keep it sorted. My first look at it was to use a TreeSet with a Comparator but the problem is the TreeSet would be with the class Taxpayer while what we need to compare is an attribute on the class Invoice.

Comment: I'm confused about your actual problem. Is the problem that you need to instantly be notified when the size of a `Map` changes? Or is the problem that you need to store the elements in a sorted order? Or is it a combination of these 2? A `TreeMap` (or `TreeSet`, depending on your needs) would definitely make it easier to maintain a collection of sorted key/value pairs.

Comment: The second one, basicly i need to run a Map containing for example 100 Taxpayers as a value and put the 10 Taxpayers that spent the most inside another collection. It doesn't need to be ordered but it's probably easier to do by ordering it.... Edit: Already edited the question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a classic Top K problem ? Maybe you can use the java.util.PriorityQueue to build a  min heap to get the top 10 Taxpayer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be broken down into 3 steps:

- Extract distinct `TaxPayer`s
- Extract `Invoice`s for each payer and then sum amount
- Sort by the payed amount and limit to first 10

If you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you can do something like:

```
final Map<TaxPayer, Double> toTenMap = payersMap.values()                       // get values from map
        .stream()                                                                   // create java.util.Stream
        .distinct()                                                                 // do not process duplicates (TaxPayer must provide a standard-compliant equals method)
        .map(taxPayer -> {
            final double totalAmount = invoicesMap
                .values()                                                           // get values from the invoices map
                .stream()                                                           // create Stream
                .filter(invoice -> invoice.getTIN().equals(taxPayer.getTIN()))      // get only those for the current TaxPayer
                .mapToDouble(Invoice::getAmount)                                    // get amount
                .sum();                                                             // sum amount
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(taxPayer, totalAmount);            // create Map.Entry
        })
        .sorted( ( entry1, entry2 ) -> {                                            // sort by total amount
            if (entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue()) return 1;
            if (entry1.getValue() < entry2.getValue()) return -1;
            return 0;
        })
        .limit(10)                                                                  // get only top ten payers
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(                                                  // save to map
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue
        ));
```

Surely there is a more elegant solution. Also, I haven't tested it because I don't have much time now.

Comment: Still got to test it, been very busy. Will try to test it out tomorrow. Thanks man.

Comment: @JoãoAmorim what is the outcome then?